# Can we add a link in a website to go directly to corresponding webpage of another website,bypassing the login page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts, single-sign-on

I'm currently working in `java web project` using `Spring MVC framework`, which is sharing a `DB(DB2)` of another old website. I've to add a link which'll direct me to corresponding webpage of the older website(Using struts 1.x). For eg,the link will carry the specific period and person name to display his salary details in older website. I tried `single sign on` which simply directs me to the logged in page of the older website. Ask me if you want more information about this issue. I hope there'll be solution, which I didn't reach yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this.If we don't concern about the security level,you can simply add a href link in jsp and pass the parameters as querystring in the form of destination website.then you can extract either using javascript or java.In javascript lots of answers available in Stackoverflow itself for extracting querystring parameters as well as for Java.To bypass the login page you need to enable SSO in sever level configuration if you're using Websphere App Server 7.
for SSO,
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Setting_up_single_sign-on_for_WebSphere_Application_Server